# Special Characters in email

Tags: email, dns, mx-record

I have an e-mail with the letters "ae" in it. Right now, i only recieve mails, if the sender types "ae". I wondered if it was possible to redirect mails if the address was spelled with 'æ' instead of "ae".

Is there a way to redirect mails from the address spelled with "æ" to the address spelled with 'ae'?

The current mail is:
'name'@'...ae...'.dk

The following mail should redirect mails to the one above:
'name'@'...æ...'.dk

Can it be done through aliasses or maybe some record?

Comment: only if you actually own the domain with the `æ` character in it.  https://www.dk-hostmaster.dk/sites/default/files/Characters%20allowed%20in.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It can be done if you buy the domain name that contains '.....æ......dk' and you create an email address that forwards all mail to '.....ae.....dk'.

ae and æ are treated differently so you really need the domain name to do a forward.

But unfortunately Windows Mail, gmail.com and hotmail.com do not support these.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!